# mpv : video problem

Tags: kubuntu, video, mpv-media-player

mpv displays some videos (10-bit?) as a checkered image, as I show in the screenshot below (I don't know how to describe it, does this have a name?):

[image: screenshot showing the issue]

Checked:

- hardware acceleration enabled/disabled
- various video output configurations (`--vd`)
- X11/Wayland
- `apt`/`snap`/FlatHub version

All these do not improve the display, sometimes the image is "normal" but of very poor quality.

VLC displays the same videos "normally".

Here are my system's details:

- Operating System: Kubuntu 23.10
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.8
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.110.0
- Qt Version: 5.15.10
- Kernel Version: 6.5.0-14-generic (64-bit)
- Graphics Platform: X11
- Processors: 12 × 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-11600 @ 2.80GHz
- Memory: 31.1 GiB of RAM
- Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® Graphics
- Manufacturer: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
- Product Name: MS-7D18
- System Version: 1.0

Here is the output of `vainfo`:

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.19.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_18
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.19 (libva 2.12.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel iHD driver for Intel(R) Gen Graphics - 23.2.3 ()
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
  VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
  VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointStats
  VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointFEI
  VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
  VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointFEI
  VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
  VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointEncPicture
  VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointFEI
  VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
  VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointFEI
  VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
  VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
  VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileVP9Profile1            : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileVP9Profile2            : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileVP9Profile3            : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileHEVCMain12             : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileHEVCMain12             : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileHEVCMain422_10         : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileHEVCMain422_10         : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileHEVCMain422_12         : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileHEVCMain422_12         : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileHEVCMain444            : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileHEVCMain444            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
  VAProfileHEVCMain444_10         : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileHEVCMain444_10         : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
  VAProfileHEVCMain444_12         : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileHEVCSccMain            : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileHEVCSccMain            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
  VAProfileHEVCSccMain10          : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileHEVCSccMain10          : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
  VAProfileHEVCSccMain444         : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileHEVCSccMain444         : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
  VAProfileAV1Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileHEVCSccMain444_10      : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileHEVCSccMain444_10      : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> mpv --gpu-api=vulkan
> ```
>
> OpenGL is the problem

<sup>Answer moved here from [OP's question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1498358/3).</sup>